# Problema al poder contabilizar el numero de palabras en un array bidimensional

Tags: c++

verán se me ha solicitado hacer un array bidimensional de [10][50], en donde se llenara con caracteres, o sea en este caso con nombres, para después me indique cuantas palabras tiene cada nombre y cuantos caracteres hay en total en el arreglo nombres, he intentado con el `size()` y con `length()`, para así poder contabilizar las letras por cada nombre en el array, acepto cualquier consejo, a continuación dejo el código en el cual se pueden ingresar los nombres y este los mostrara en pantalla, no he puesto mis otros prototipos por que no quería enredar mas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=0,nletras;
     char nombres[10][50];
    
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Cargue los nombres de los empleados de la empresa: ";
        gets(nombres[i]);
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<"Nombres ingresados: ";
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        puts(nombres[i]);
        cout<<"Contiene: "<<nletras<<" letras."<<endl;
    }
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo es que en c++ no es recomendable usar `gets` ni `puts`. En su lugar tienes `cin` y `cout`.

Sobre el problema...para saber el tamaño de cada función deberías tener un array de int para poder almacenarlos. Además, puedes hacer uso de una función que averigüe la longitud. Sabiendo que cada cadena acaba en `'\0'` puedes recorrer cada nombre introducido e ir contando los caracteres que lo componen:

```
int CalcularTamNombre(const char* nombre)
{
    int i=0;
    while (nombre[i]!= '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Esta función la puedes usar para llenar el array de tamaños. Cada vez que vayas a introducir un nombre, calculas su tamaño y lo metes en el array:

```
for (i=0;i<num_nombres;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Cargue los nombres de los empleados de la empresa: ";
        cin>>nombres[i];
        tamannos[i] = CalcularTamNombre(nombres[i]);
        cout<<"\n";

    }
```

Por último, teniendo el array de tamaños de nombres, saber el total es tan fácil como recorrerlo e ir sumando cada componente:

```
int total = 0;
    for (i=0;i<num_nombres;i++)
    {
        total+= tamannos[i];
    }
```

Todo junto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int CalcularTamNombre(const char* nombre);

int main()
{
    const int num_nombres = 10;
    int i=0, nletras;
    char nombres[num_nombres][50];
    int tamannos[num_nombres];

    for (i=0;i<num_nombres;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Cargue los nombres de los empleados de la empresa: ";
        cin>>nombres[i];
        tamannos[i] = CalcularTamNombre(nombres[i]);
        cout<<"\n";

    }
    cout<<"Nombres ingresados: "<<endl;
    for (i=0;i<num_nombres;i++)
    {
        cout<<nombres[i]<<" contiene: "<<tamannos[i]<<" letras."<<endl;
    }
    int total = 0;
    for (i=0;i<num_nombres;i++)
    {
        total+= tamannos[i];
    }
    cout<<"El total de caracteres es: "<<total<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int CalcularTamNombre(const char* nombre)
{
    int i=0;
    while (nombre[i]!= '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```